# How can i covert this method by using try and catch for xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is the code of "fetchData" method. I want to implement this code into `try - Catch` block.

How can I change.

```
 var error: NSError?

 if let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject]
 {
    //if not nil
    players = fetchedResults
 }
 else {
    println("could not fetch data \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way you can do it...

```
do {
     fetchedResults = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
      //Success....Do your stuff
} catch let error as NSError {
     //Failure ...catch error
     print("could not fetch data \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
 }
```

Comment: thank u so much..!!!

Comment: Good answer. Don't forget to put  `players = fetchedResults`  at the bottom of `do {  }`

Comment: @Swinny89 Instead I just write success block.... :)